# Draw a flower using canvas and a loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw this 
[flower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmglX.png) using a loop in canvas. I'm confused where to start. Do i draw the petals first? Do i transform them after to get all 5 petals. This is what I have so far for a 500 x 500 canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('flowerCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 20;
var petals =  5;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 250, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fill();
ctx.save();

ctx.translate(250,250);


for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  ctx.lineTo(200,0);

  ctx.stroke();
}

ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) to buffer complex paths

You can use a [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) object to store each petal. It has the same path functionality as the 2D context so code can easily be converted to a 2D path and then rendered without the need to do all the path creation steps. If you have a lot of rendering that involves many repeated paths this will give you some additional performance.

#### Create path

You create the petal relative to its rotation point.

```
function createPetal(length, width){

    const path = new Path2D();
    // draw outer line
    path.moveTo(0,0);
    path.lineTo(length * 0.3, -width);
    path.lineTo(length * 0.8, -width);
    path.lineTo(length, 0);
    path.lineTo(length * 0.8, width);
    path.lineTo(length * 0.3, width);
    // close the path so that it goes back to start
    path.closePath();

    // create the line down the middle.
    path.moveTo(0,0);
    path.lineTo(length,0);

    return path;
}
```

***Note*** for this to work the petals must be drawn relative to the rotation point.

#### Render path

You now need to draw the path several times around the circle.

```
// x,y is center
// count number of petals
// startAt is the angle of the first
function drawPetals(x, y, count, startAt, petal){
    const step = (Math.PI * 2) / count;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y); // set center
    ctx.rotate(startAt);  // set start angle
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i+= 1){
        ctx.stroke(petal);  // draw a petal
        ctx.rotate(step);   // rotate to the next
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // restore default
}
```

#### Put it all together.

Now all you need to do is create a petal, then draw them, and add a circle at the center

```
// col is the stroke color
// linewidth is the thing to do with lines
// fitScale is how well to fit the space. Less than one to fit the canvas
// petalCount i will let you guess what that does.
function drawFlower(col, lineWidth,fitScale, petalCount) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = col;
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  const size = Math.min(ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height) * fitScale * 0.5;
  drawPetals(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2, 5, 0, createPetal(size, size * 0.2));
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2, size*0.15 , 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fill();
}
```

#### The code above runs

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function createPetal(length, width) {

  const path = new Path2D();
  path.moveTo(0, 0);
  path.lineTo(length * 0.3, -width);
  path.lineTo(length * 0.8, -width);
  path.lineTo(length, 0);
  path.lineTo(length * 0.8, width);
  path.lineTo(length * 0.3, width);
  path.closePath();
  path.moveTo(0, 0);
  path.lineTo(length, 0);

  return path;
}


// x,y is center
// count number of petals
// startAt is the angle of the first
function drawPetals(x, y, count, startAt, petal) {
  const step = (Math.PI * 2) / count;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
  ctx.rotate(startAt);
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
    ctx.stroke(petal);
    ctx.rotate(step);
  }
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // restore default
}


function drawFlower(col, lineWidth, fitScale, petalCount) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = col;
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  const size = Math.min(ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height) * fitScale * 0.5;
  drawPetals(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2, 5, 0, createPetal(size, size * 0.2));
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2, size*0.15 , 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fill();
}


drawFlower("black",4,0.95,5);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

#### For browsers without `Path2D`

Not all browsers support `Path2D`. To do the same you can store the path of the petal as an array. As there are several paths and one is open and the other closed you need to add some path drawing rules. In this case is the last point is the same as the first, the path is closed.

```
// the array holds normalised coords that need to be scaled when drawing
const petal = [
    [ [0,0],[0.3,-1],[0.8,-1],[1,0],[0.8,1],[0.3,1],[0,0] ],
    [ [0,0],[1,0] ],
]
```

So now rather than create petal you have a function that draws a petal using a path

```
function drawPetal(path,width,height){
   var i = 0;
   do{  // loop through paths
       const p = path[i];
       let j = 0;       
       ctx.moveTo(p[j][0] * width, p[j ++][1] * height);
       while(j < p.length - 1){
           ctx.lineTo(p[j][0] * width, p[j ++][1] * height);
       }
       // is the path closed ?
       if(p[j][0] === p[0][0] && p[j][1] === p[0][1]){
          ctx.closePath();
       }else{
          ctx.lineTo(p[j][0] * width,p[j][1] * height)
       }
   } while(++i < path.length);
}
```

And the draw flower function needs to be changed to use the new `drawPetal` but the method is the same, draw each petal in turn rotating it using the current transform.

#### As code example

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const petal = [
  [
    [0, 0],
    [0.3, -1],
    [0.7, -1],
    [1, 0],
    [0.7, 1],
    [0.3, 1],
    [0, 0]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0]
  ],
];

function drawPetal(path, width, height) {
  var i = 0;
  do { // loop through paths
    const p = path[i];
    let j = 0;
    ctx.moveTo(p[j][0] * width, p[j++][1] * height);
    while (j < p.length - 1) {
      ctx.lineTo(p[j][0] * width, p[j++][1] * height);
    }
    if (p[j][0] === p[0][0] && p[j][1] === p[0][1]) { // is the path closed ?
      ctx.closePath();
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(p[j][0] * width, p[j][1] * height)
    }
  } while (++i < path.length);
}

function drawPetals(x, y, count, startAt, petal, width, height) {
  const step = (Math.PI * 2) / count;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
  ctx.rotate(startAt);
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
    drawPetal(petal, width, height);
    ctx.rotate(step);
  }
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore default
}

function drawFlower(col, lineWidth, fitScale, petalCount) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = col;
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  const size = Math.min(ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height) * fitScale * 0.5;
  ctx.beginPath();

  drawPetals(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2, 5, -Math.PI / 2, petal, size, size * 0.2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2, size * 0.15, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fill();
}


drawFlower("black", 4, 0.95, 5);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: +1 wow thank you so much for this detailed answer. i really appreciate you taking the time on it! i'm going to read it through now.

Comment: is there a way to do it without Path2D?

Comment: @applechips Yes see second half of anwser starting at the heading **"For browsers without `Path2D`"**